# Dual Comparator Circuit

Tags: analog, comparator, pnp

I've received a board with the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpb25B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The **INPUT** is a digital signal coming from a MCU, with HIGH value being 3.3V. Based on received INPUT, the circuit should operate in two states:

- STATE 1 : When **INPUT** is **HIGH**, **OUTPUT1** is **HIGH** and **OUTPUT2** is **LOW**
- STATE 2 : When **INPUT** is **LOW**, **OUTPUT1** is **LOW** and **OUTPUT2** is **HIGH**

**OUTPUT HIGH = -7V**
**OUTPUT LOW = 0V**

The circuit was tested and controlled by a MCU, worked fine in both states. However, when we tested another MCU, we started with **STATE 1**, and then driven the **INPUT LOW**, but it didn't switch to **STATE2**. In fact, it kept holding in **STATE 1**. And it only goes to **STATE 2** when we touched the input channel with Voltmeter. We tried to add a pulldown circuit but that didn't solve the case.

Q1 & Q2 are BC516-D27Z

---

EDIT:

1. Updated with the correct circuit schematic.
2. Added OUTPUT HIGH/LOW values.
3. Both MCUs are the same.

Comment: Are your transistors meant to be upside down?

Comment: Please confirm that you checked both outputs to make sure they were always LOW/HIGH or HIGH/LOW. Is the "board" a PC board where all the connections are soldered or a breadboard with push-in connections? Where did the board come from? +/- 7 volts is an unusual supply, and an output high of 7 volts, more so. When either op amp output is high, it's exceeding the Vbe AMR of the transistor it feeds. When either output is low, it's short-circuited. It should still work in both cases. All that's needed is a level shift  from 3.4 V to 7 V. There are much simpler ways to do it.

Comment: Do you have a good ground connection between the mcu and the comparators circuit?

Comment: @IanBland a PNP in CE configuration. that's the symbol from LTspice

Comment: @stretch I've corrected the circuit schematic. Answering your questions, It's a soldered board an old colleague designed. It has different functions, and one functions is this circuit, that a specific SPST switch that requires HIGH range from -5V to -7V. and yes the both OP-AMP states did not conflict. However, sometimes the HIGH output drops to -4.6V when loading on the SPST, but it still functioning.

Comment: @James The board has different inputs/outputs with MCU for another functions, and it works properly, except for this circuit.

Comment: @Fmashehri Your circuit schematic has basic mistakes. Double check that the supply voltage polarities match the transistor polarity. "PNP in CE configuration. that's the symbol from LTspice" - what? LTspice gives you transistors, it's up to you to set them up correctly.

Comment: There should be resistors from the op-amp outputs to the base of the transistors. As shown, the op-amp may go into current limit or other undefined behavior, possibly oscillation.

Comment: I ran the simulation and there is definitely about 300 mA into the base of the transistors. But after trying a couple simulations I was blocked and it demanded registration. (Somehow I got logged out) After logging in here, I can't use CircuitLab at all :(

Comment: @Fmashehri Can you edit the question and ask a specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AD820 is an op-amp, not a comparator. It's a rather lousy comparator in terms of speed, and for this application a simple LM393 powered from +/-7V would work much better.

If the circuit is as you have drawn, then you're using the PNPs with collector and emitter swapped. They will operate with a very low current gain. That's not what you want. If that's how the circuit was assembled, then that's your problem. Flip the transistors upside down and things will start to work.

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiC4PO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output is indeed complementary:

[image: The complementary outputs of the corrected circuit]

But all this seems like a whole lot of work for little gain. This same circuit could be put together with a couple MOSFETs in place of the op-amp. To retain the spirit of the original circuit, I've decided to leave two BJTs there :)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0CcQw.png)</sup>

The cost is 5x lower than that of an AD820. Instead of using 6 discrete MOSFETs, this could also be a single chip - CD4007, for the same cost, but higher level of integration.

The output switches in about 100ns, and is driven push-pull, i.e. without pull-ups. The static current consumption of this circuit is about 0.2mA.

[image: The output waveform of a MOSFET-based circuit]

For an even lower cost, an LM393 circuit will do the job:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEvfsN.png)</sup>

The output switches reasonably quickly still:

[image: The output waveform of a comparator-based circuit]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've corrected the PNP placement, both of them are in CE configuration. As I mentioned, the circuit work perfectly when tested alone -input received from function generator and first MCU- , but fail to switch from state 1 to 2 when input is received from the the second MCU. Yes, it would be easier to change the circuit. but for an implemented PCB, it would be difficult.

Comment: What concerns more is the capacitance-like behavior that happens in the input.

Comment: @Fmashehri Well, how does that input from 1st MCU and 2nd MCU look on an oscilloscope? And also: you're literally throwing money away. It'll be cheaper to redesign the pcb and run it at PCBway or JCLPCB, than to use those op-amps. I'm still amazed that you'd pick such an expensive chip when there are so many low-cost alternatives that perform much better. As for PCB layouts for such circuits: treat them as disposable. It's so easy to make a new one, it's not worth worrying about. The hard part is always the actual design.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the simulation, and also added 1k resistors to the op-amps' outputs. Here is a plot of the DC sweep from 2V to 4V:

[image: Dual Comparator]

I see that I don't know how to do a DC sweep. I tried V(INPUT) but that gave me an error. And now CircuitLab has locked me out again.

And I see that I need to add a voltage source as @KubaHasntForgottenMonica has in their answer, but I can't use CircuitLab anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately, DC sweep in CircuitLab is somewhat broken - not the sweep part, but the solver reusing results from the previous operating point. So even when there are no errors, you can get very glitchy output curve. As for sweeping input voltage, you'd sweep INPUT.V, and this would have to be selected from a dropdown in the DC Sweep pane.